# How can I differentiate "stack" memory from dynamic memory in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Say I have a routine `foo()` that calls a routine `bar(argument)`. `Argument` can either be a declaration "on the stack" (drawing a parallel to C) or it can be dynamically allocated. How can I inquire inside `bar()` if `argument` memory was allocated with the first or the second method ?

Comment: In C it can be both on the stack or heap.

Comment: Is this purely a curiosity issue or are you trying to solve a particular problem?

Comment: @Rook better you don't know...

Answer (score 5):

The best thing would be to see the assembly code. Arrays will be typically on the heap and local scalars on the stack, but there is no standard fortran inquire function for that and your code should not depend on these details.